# Add row to batch of TensorFlow Tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have rank 3 tensors [batch_size, num_rows, num_cols]) to which I would like to append rows of the appropriate size, resulting in rank 3 tensors with dimensions [batch_size, num_rows + 1, num_cols]

For example, if I have the following batch of 2x2 matrices

```
batch = [ [[2, 2],
           [2, 2]],
          [[3, 3],
           [3, 3]],
          [[4, 4],
           [4, 4]] ]
```

and a new row `v = [1, 1]` I would like to append, then the desired result is

```
new_batch = [ [[2, 2],
               [2, 2],
               [1, 1]], 
              [[3, 3],
               [3, 3],
               [1, 1]],
              [[4, 4],
               [4, 4],
               [1, 1]] ]
```

Is there a simple way to do this in TensorFlow?  Here is what I tried:

```
W, b, c0, q0 = params
c = tf.concat([context, c0], axis=1)
q_p = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(W, question) + b)
q = tf.concat([q_p, q0], axis=1)
q_mask = tf.concat([question_mask, 1], axis=1)
```

To clarify the terms,

1. `context` has dimensions `[batch_size, context_len, hidden_size]`
2. `q_p` has dimensions `[batch_size, question_len, hidden_size]`
3. `question_mask` has dimensions `[batch_size, question_len]`
4. `c0` and `q0` both have dimensions `[hidden_size]`

What I want to do

1. add vector `c0` to `context`, resulting in a Tensor with dimensions `[batch_size, context_len + 1, hidden_size]`
2. add vector `q0` to `q_p`, resulting in a Tensor with dimensions `[batch_size, question_len + 1, hidden_size]`
3. add a 1 to `question_mask`, resulting in a Tensor with dimensions `[batch_size, question_len + 1]`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what did you try to do?

Comment: I've added my attempt and relevant details to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) to do this.

```
batch = [ [[2, 2],
           [2, 2]],
          [[3, 3],
           [3, 3]],
          [[4, 4],
           [4, 4]] ]

row_to_add = [1,1]

t = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch, dtype=np.float32)
appended_t = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.concat((x, [row_to_add]), axis=0), t)
```

## output

```
appended_t.eval(session=tf.Session())

array([[[ 2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 4.,  4.],
        [ 4.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  1.]]], dtype=float32)
```